# I had a question migrated from supseruser. What steps can I take to associate the question with my new SF account?

Tags: support, migration, moderation, moving-questions

Just as the question says, how can i get my migrated question associated with my account?
Here is the question in question:
[My web-page doesn't seem to be available on other computers (the www)](https://serverfault.com/questions/209049/my-web-page-doesnt-seem-to-be-available-on-other-computers-the-www)

How can I contact a moderator for assistance?

Answer (score 2):

This [should happen automatically](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/) if you're using the same OpenID on all SE sites... I would contact a mod if this is not the case.

Comment: how do I contact a moderator?

Comment: You may need to associate your accounts if you did not do so the first time you were prompted (when you created the account on the additional sites). [Check here first](http://serverfault.com/users/62550?tab=accounts). If it's not there to be associated, contact SF using the "Contact US" address at the very bottom of every page.